# How Can I Quickly Group Over A Million Items by a Property

Tags: c#

I built a program that parses a list of Fix Messages, storing them as quote messages. These Fix Messages are in the form of over 1.5GB of zipped text files.

```
public class Contract
{
    public string ExchangeId { get; set; } = "?";
    public string ExchangeSymbol { get; set; } // Setting this property in my code.
    // I also group Quote by this property below in my dictionary, see below.
}


public class Quote
{
   public Contract Contract = new Contract();
   public decimal Ask = 0M;
   public decimal Bid = 0M;
   // ...
}

public class QuoteMessage
{
   public List<Quote> Quotes = new List<Quote>();
   // ...
}
```

Each `QuoteMessage` can have multuiple quotes. I store them in a `List<QuoteMessage>`. After this list is generated, I need to bucket quotes (not quote messages) by their contract to analyze them. To do so I run a `SelectMany` and extract a list of quotes from each `QuoteMessage`, feeding them into a dictionary of `Dictionary<Contract, List<Quote>>`. I make sure I have the proper `IComparable<Contract>` in place when I initialize the dictionary.

The problem is that it takes almost half an hour to go over each element in the list and insert them into the dictionary as such:

```
public Dictionary<Contract, List<Quote>> SortQuoteByContract(List<Quote> quotes)
{
    var contractDict = new Dictionary<Contract, List<Quote>>(new IComparable<Contract>());
    foreach (Quote quote in quotes)
    {
        if (!contractDict.ContainsKey(quote.Contract))
        {
            contractDict[quote.Contract] = new List<Quote>();
        }
        contractDict[quote.Contract] = quote; // Line A

    return contractDict;
}
```

Is there a way to speed this up? As I understand, I'm not creating any copies of the quote itself (on Line A), just storing a pointer to its location in memory in the `<Contract, List<Quote>>` dictionary. Is this correct? I want to make this grouping as fast as possible. Once the quotes are grouped by contract, I can run my analysis on all of them in seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: The line `contractDict[quote.Contract]  = quote` looks wrong. Do you mean `contractDict[quote.Contract].Add(quote)` ?

Comment: You should know about `ILookup` (and the `ToLookup`) extension method. It is effectively a dictionary with multiple keys per value. It could replace all of the above with `quotes.ToLookup(q => q.Contract)`

Comment: If you use Contract as a hash key, quality of hash function is crucial. How do you define it?

Comment: Is the intermediate `List` really required? Can't you just `ToLookup` your original data source?

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd That's what o meant to write. I mistyped. I'll check out ILookup

Comment: @spender The contrast on List<Quote> are naturally ordered by time. Will ILookup preserve the original order in the list?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk Yes, but it's probably an implementation detail and not safe to rely on. :(

Comment: @TeeZadAwk - What's up with `new IComparable<Contract>()`? You can't create instances of interfaces.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk - And the assignment `contractDict[quote.Contract] = quote` is invalid.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk - Can you please post your real code?

Answer (score 1):

This code, using `PLINQ` and `ToLookup`, will certainly be faster than your current code.  It is also very easy to read and, from the method consumer's end, very easy to use.

It will require you to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `Contract` class, or write a class that implements `IComparer<Contract>`, which is just an external interface for `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

```
public ILookup<Contract, Quote> SortQuoteByContract(List<Quote> quotes) =>
    quotes.AsParallel().ToLookup(_ => _.Contract);

public ILookup<Contract, Quote> SortQuoteByContract(List<Quote> quotes) =>
    quotes.AsParallel().ToLookup(_ => _.Contract, new ContractComparer());
```

Comment: How does .ToLookup(_ => _.Contract) know how to compare contracts?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk You can either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `Contract` class, or write a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Contract>` and pass it to the override of `ToLookup` that takes an `IEqualityComparer<Contract>`

Comment: What would need to be added in ContractComparer if I wanted to sort by Timestamp (DateTime) as well?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk `ToLookup` isn't going to sort so much as it's going to group into buckets by the key.  From your example code, your basic `Equals` implementation would check for equality of two `Contract` objects' `ExchangeId` and `ExchangeSymbol` properties.  If you want `ToLookup` to group `Contract`s with identical `Id`s and `Symbol`s separately by their date, you'd need to add a `DateTime` property to `Contract` and then include a comparison of that value in `Equals`.

Comment: As such? https://pastebin.com/Xmdhry1D

How would I know if this sorts it by ascending or descending timestamp order? (Let's pretend Quote has a DateTime field called Timestamp)

Comment: Though if you want to sort by date, you could consider implementing your own `ISortedLookup` and `ToISortedLookup` interface and extension method, or, alternately, keeping a separate, sorted list of contracts to iterate over later as keys to your ILookup (which will not have any guaranteed sorting when you enumerate over it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for optimizations, you should find the places where memory allocations take place. In your case, an allocation takes place each time you create a new list, and could possibly happen each time you add an item to the list.

Take another approach that dispenses with the dictionary altogether: sort the list by contract, and then iterate through the list.

Imagine you had a separate batch processor class:

```
interface IContractBatchProcessor
{
     void OnContractStart(Contract contract);
     void ProcessQuote(Quote quote);
     void OnContractEnd()
}
```

Now you can process the list like this:

```
static int CompareByContract(Quote q1, Quote q2) 
{
    // TODO
}

void Process(List<Quote> quote, IContractBatchProcessor processor)
{
    list.Sort(CompareByContract);
    Contract lastContract = null;
    foreach(var quote in list)
    {
        if(quote.Contract != lastContract)
        {
            if(lastContract != null)
            {
                processor.OnContractEnd();
            }
            processor.OnContractStart(quote.Contract);
            lastContract = quote.Contract;
        }
        processor.ProcessQuote(quote);
    }
    processor.OnContractEnd();
}
```

This is running the [List.Sort method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) that takes a delegate as a parameter.

The approach would be faster because you are performing an inplace sort of the list, so there are no extra memory allocations.

Comment: What is OnContractEnd supposed to do? Is CompareByContract an IComparable?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk: Your question doesn't say what the processing actually involves, so it can do whatever you need it to, which might be nothing. And `CompareByContract` can be a static method. (I've added the signature for you).

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I see you're implementing the strategy pattern here. Which will be very useful for my use case. I can now clean up my messy code.